# Data does not appear after the transition to the listview with jquerymobile

Tags: jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

I'm Trying to display the display data from listview by adding a link to the next page but when a new page of data does not appear to be on the page reload or refresh the page using F5 , how when the time at the click of the data appearing on a new page?

```
$(document).on('pageinit',function(){
    document.getElementById("pesan").style.display = 'none';
    $.mobile.loading('show');
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://localhost/samplingserver/json_pm.php",
        crossDomain: true,
        cache: false,
        timeout: 3000,
        error: function(){
                $.mobile.loading('hide');
                document.getElementById("pesan").style.display = 'block';
            },              
        success: function(result){
            var result=$.parseJSON(result);
            $.each(result, function(i, element){        
                var id_pm=element.id_pm;
                var nama_project=element.nama_project;  
                var lokasi=element.lokasi;
                var tanggal=element.tanggal;
                var list="<li><a href='sampling_pm.html?id_pm="+id_pm+"&nama_project="+nama_project+"' data-transition='slide'><h2>"+ nama_project + "</h2></a></li>";
                $("#listsampling").append(list);    
                $('#listsampling').listview().listview('refresh');
                $.mobile.loading('hide');

                document.getElementById("pesan").style.display = 'none';
            }); 
            }
        });     
});
```

Comment: You means you get the data in first page?And want to get a particular '<li>' data in second page?

Comment: Thanks @Homen , yeah right I get the data on the first page and when I click on the data in '<li>' the first page it will appear on the second page , but when he moved to the second page of data does not immediately appear to be in the new reload appear .

Comment: I am not getting the problem.In second page, when you reload the data is not showing or what?